# import SDWebImage fails despite CocoaPod installation

Tags: ios, cocoapods, sdwebimage

I have inserted SDWebImage to the `Podfile`

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'

pod 'NSData+Base64', '~> 1.0'
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.23'
pod 'CrashlyticsFramework', '~> 2.2'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'
pod 'NewRelicAgent', '~> 4.186'
pod 'GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.10'
pod 'Reachability', '~> 3.2'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.7'
```

followed by:

```
pod install
pod update
```

It is all succesfuly installed.

But when I open the workspace and try to access the library I get this upon importing `#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>`

```
TNCViewController.m:12:9: 'SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h' file not found
```

Under Pods project I can see Pods/SDWebImage

and I have added manually `ImageIO.framework` to Linked Frameworks and Libraries.

What else can I do?  Never experienced such problem with a cocoapod library before.

**Update**
I have found the problem !!

If I remove the `Target Membership` for the Unit tests, then it compiles !!
This also happened on a fresh project where I copied the files over.

This means the Pod install doesn't install the files for the test target. Any idea what I could do please?

Comment: Try deleting all the pods and podlock file, and re installing them again.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it. It doesn't help.

Comment: Remove the version 3.7 and then update the pod again. It will install a latest version of pod. Hope that might help

Comment: I just tried it. No change as it was already `3.7.2`.

Comment: This is totally weird as i am using it in one of my project.

Comment: I just created a new project and it works.  Darn. I don't know what else I could do. I deleted the `Pods` folder and `Podfile.lock`, what else can I do, to reset the whole state?

Comment: I hope other libraries are not conflicting any where with SdWebImage. Have you added all the libraries in the new folder?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I mean in a new  project not folder

Comment: I have started a new project with all the cocodspods. No conflict. All works. I even used https://github.com/kylef/cocoapods-deintegrate to remove cocoapads from my former project and reinstalled everything. I removed the derived data and rebuilt. No chance.  Instead of coding I am cocoa poding for 1.5 hours.  I am now porting everything to the new project.  Wasted so much time :(

Comment: I can understand. I have also wasted hours sometimes. Sorry i couldn't able to help you

Comment: @Jassi I found the problem. Please have a look at the updated question.

Comment: For test target it wont show an error if you import I guess. If it shows an error you can add it in Pod file so it will install for test target. Check and let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the solution !!

I instaled first Cocoa Pods deintegrate: https://github.com/kylef/cocoapods-deintegrate

```
pod deintegrate
rm Podfile.lock
rm Podfile
pod init
vim Podfile
```

-> My Pod file now looks like this:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'News' do

pod 'NSData+Base64', '~> 1.0'
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.23'
pod 'CrashlyticsFramework', '~> 2.2'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'
pod 'NewRelicAgent', '~> 4.186'
pod 'GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.10'
pod 'Reachability', '~> 3.2'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.7'

end

target 'NewsTests' do

pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.7'

end
```

Now it works.  The reason is that if you mark your ViewController to become part of the Test Target, you also need the library in the Test Target.

I should have ran `pod init` in first place. It is not that optional as the documentation claims it to be.

Hope this helps others and save them hours of frustration

Comment: Thats what i told you in my last comment. Good job that you find it yourself.

Comment: Thank you, yeah it was a big pain.